# Changing bazel build output folder on Windows while build tensorflow frm source

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build Tensorflow 1.14.0-rc1 on

```
Windows 10
python : 3.6.8
cudatoolkit : 10.1
cudnn : 7.6.1
bazel : 0.25.1
```

While building bazel gives linking error due to low storage on default location of **~/*baze*{username}_** so I tried to change output location of build using *[--output_user_root](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--output_user_root)* which gives error

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package output_user_root=/e/build/tensorflow

ERROR: Unrecognized option: --output_user_root=/e/build/tensorflow
```

when building using

or

```
E:\tensorflow-1.14.0-rc1>bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package -output_user_root=E:\build\tensorflow

ERROR: Unrecognized option: --output_user_root=E:\build\tensorflow
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--output_user_root` is a [startup option](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#startup-options), so it must go before the command, i.e.:

```
bazel --output_user_root=<...> build <...>
```